# How to convert and update the currency in magento 2 on place order

Tags: orders, magento2.3

I am modifying the order using aroundPlaceOrder Hook, in same hook I am trying to update  the totals .My currency selection is INR so I want to convert it to base currency and update the value.

```
        $address->setBaseSubtotal($finalPrice);
        $address->setSubtotal($finalPrice);
        $address->setDiscountAmount($discount);
        $address->setTaxAmount($tax);
        $address->setBaseTaxAmount($tax);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal);
        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
```

Currenct results : 
[image]
 Required Results :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could Achieve this using following code . just pass the value in convertPrice() and get the base currency converted code and save the same to base currency:

```
            $address->setBaseSubtotal($baseFinalPrice);
            $address->setSubtotal($finalPrice);
            $address->setDiscountAmount($discount);
            $address->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseDiscount);
            $address->setTaxAmount($tax);
            $address->setBaseTaxAmount($baseTax);
            $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal);
            $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
```

Conversion functions

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory
 */
protected $currencyFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
}

/**
 * Convert base price value to store price value
 *
 * @param $amountValue
 * @return float
 */
public function convertPrice($amountValue)
{
    $currentCurrency = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
    $baseCurrency = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();
    if ($currentCurrency != $baseCurrency) {
        $rate = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currentCurrency)->getAnyRate($baseCurrency);
        $amountValue = $amountValue * $rate;
    }

    return $amountValue;
}
```